# GAE (Google App engine) generated emails go to hotmail junk folder

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gmail, hotmail, dkim

I am sending emails from my google app engine app via Java api.  I am using the standard code:

```java
final Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(adminEmail, "Admin"));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailAddress, user.getFullName()));
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setContent(msgBody, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
Transport.send(msg);
```

I have also setup DKIM according to the documentation on google apps as outlined here:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124?hl=en

By adding the following TXT records on my godaddy domain setup:

host:google._domainkey

TXT Value key:v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCimg+guqUdZpdgenPAfg4/pDpS4iMoxUZyCLd4ARk22lVtbS/O74x1x7RBYwesvcq2qHQc6RXh/XFbCd807v4HLCVBT3KQlBtpkP1MXlaVKpoPPzEm+oNQEuGA+eXUOb6Sa/jeNitgKlJow/bLh/Qizh/hgHNhrvsnU1snU5RAFwIDAQAB

Also:

-the adminEmail account I am sending the emails from has been added as an owner of the google app engine application.

-It has been more than 48 hours since I set this up.

-My emails do not go to junk for gmail, only hotmail.

Am I missing something?  Why are my mails going to junk for hotmail?

Answer (score 0):

Different email providers have different filters for identifying messages as spam. While including things like DKIM headers improves deliverability, it doesn't guarantee it - after all, a spammer can have their own DKIM headers just as well as you can. But if you're just developing your own app, you can help guide Hotmail's valuation of your domain early on by marking it as not spam.